# Storing Proc mean variables in SAS

Tags: sas

```
    proc means data=har.&seg_cell n mean std p1 p50 p99;
    class segment;
    var txn tpv;
    output out=stat_1 (drop = _TYPE_ _FREQ_) 
    P1(txn)=txn_P1_T P1(tpv)=tpv_P1_T
    P99(txn)=txn_P99_T P99(tpv)=tpv_P99_T
    ;
    where POS_flag = &POS and cell=&gcell;
    title "Stat Summary - Test_POS";
    run;

    data har.&seg_cell;
    if _N_=1 then set stat_1; 
    set har.&seg_cell;
    run;
```

I want to save the P1 P50 P99 for both TXN and TPV Segment wise(segment has 10 different names)  into  separate variables. But when ever I run this code only the overall(all segments)  P1 P50 P99 getting stored for all the rows.

what I want is depending on the segment that particula P1 P50 P99 should be added.

Please kindly help me with this and pardon me for my bad vocab.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Sort your source data set by `segment`
2. Use the **NWAY** option to eliminate the "grand total" observation from the `MEANS` output data set (**_*TYPE*_**=0).
3. Merge the output data set back to your source.

So, a complete solution should be something like this:

```
proc sort data=har.&seg_cell;
   by segment;
run;
proc means nway data=har.&seg_cell n mean std p1 p50 p99;
  class segment;
  var txn tpv;
  output out=stat_1 (drop = _TYPE_ _FREQ_) 
         P1(txn)=txn_P1_T P1(tpv)=tpv_P1_T
         P99(txn)=txn_P99_T P99(tpv)=tpv_P99_T;
  where POS_flag = &POS and cell=&gcell;
  title "Stat Summary - Test_POS";
run;

data har.&seg_cell;
   merge har.&seg_cell stat_1;
      by segment;
run;
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `nway` option isn't strictly necessary but maybe it's best to use it anyway. Otherwise, I guess you could end up with an extra (unmatched) observation in your final dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `by segment` instead of `class`. Note you'll have to sort your dataset by `segment` first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the summary data for each `segment` merged into the proper rows, you will need to do a `merge by` instead of using `if _N_=1`.